# What's this exterior wall treatment and how should I paint it?

Tags: walls, painting, maintenance, old-house, pressure-washer

I need to paint the exterior walls of this house, but I am not sure what is the material of the walls.

I know this type of houses came from Finland to to south of Argentina because they are excellent for very cold weathers.

Also I would like to know if I have to use latex paint and/or washing first with soap and a pressure washer machine (like the one uses to wash cars).

[image: a picture of the house]
[image: another picture of the house]
[image: one more picture of the house]

Comment: I think that's exposed aggregate concrete, but I don't know any special methods for painting it, I'd think just a brush or a very nappy roller.

Comment: Pebble dash is the look of it but yours appears to be precast panels of concrete with the exposed pebbles. Is that a vinyl channel between the panels or caulking?

Comment: It's not always a good idea to paint masonry or stucco. Some of it needs to breathe to avoid damage, mildew, etc.

Comment: http://www.kerkstra.com/architectural-panels.html. Something like this company makes

Comment: @Kris They are panels of 0.5 cm and the unions have silicone caulk. It seams to be something like cork with pebble.

Comment: @batsplatsterson it isn't concrete because it is a flexible and light precast panels that came by boat from Finland to Argentina.

Comment: I thought exposed agregret panels also, maybe a better photo is needed since several thought the same thing, edit the composition into your question or there will probably be others that miss the cork part.